# Order items with multiple status codes - only need first transaction for each line item

Tags: oracle, duplicates, row, minimum

I have a Oracle table that contains transaction records for orders.  Each line item (a.SLLITM) on each order (a.SLDOCO) goes through multiple status points (a.SLLTTR).  I am trying to capture the first status point - status may vary.  Logically my thought is to use the minimum value from the "Hour" field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
SELECT 
to_char(to_date(a.SLTRDJ +1900000, 'yyyyddd'), 'mm/dd/yyyy') "Order Date",
a.SLDCTO "Order Type",
a.SLDOCO "Order Number",
a.SLLITM "2nd Item Number",
a.SLTORG "Transaction Originator",
substr(TRIM(a.SLKCOO),3,3)||'500' "Branch",
    to_char(substr(lpad(to_char(to_number(lpad(a.SLTDAY,6,0),'000000')),6,0),1,2),'00') "Hour",
a.SLFRTH "Ship Via"

FROM    PRODDTA.F42199 a

    WHERE a.SLDCTO IN ('CS','SO','ST') 
    AND a.SLLNTY IN ('S','SS') 
    AND a.SLLTTR IN ('520, '540')
    AND a.SLTRDJ > 117050
    AND a.SLKCOO IN ('00200', '00600')
```

Comment: Which one is the "hour" field (column!) and what is its data type?

Comment: a.SLTDAY - it's a whole number

Comment: lol - the **HOUR** column is called SLT**DAY** and its data type is `NUMBER`. Why?

Comment: TDAY = Time of Day

Comment: Oh, so the content of the column is not "hour" but rather the time-of-day component of the Oracle `DATE` data type? So for example the value may be 134438 meaning 13:44:38 in 24-hour notation? That makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, I'm only using the hour.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Question then, though (showing why the Oracle `DATE` data type, with the date and time-of-day together, makes more sense): What if the first status was at 23:55 PM, and then the transaction extended over midnight and there are other rows with values like 1:30 AM (the next day)? You surely don't want the 1:30 AM record, you want the 23:55 PM record, and the SLTDAY column alone will not help you with that.

Comment: I'm ok with taking that risk.  Normal business hours are 7AM to 5PM.  Would be extremely rare to have a transaction that late.

Comment: The issue is not 23:55 PM. You may have a transaction begin at 4:45 PM and then extend to 7:05 AM the next morning. Anyway: It seems you could use the `FIRST/LAST` function, either analytic version or aggregate version depending on your needs. Do you only want one row per order? Then `GROUP BY` the columns in `SELECT`, and add `min(stllttr) keep (dense_rank first order by sltday)` to `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, just one row per order.  We are trying to plan warehouse staff around order entry activity.  Knowing hour of the first status point for each line gives me the order entry time for the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your tables, I can't demonstrate on them. Instead, here is how one would select, in the SCOTT schema (standard on Oracle installations), the JOB of the employee with the earliest HIREDATE in each DEPARTMENT.

Notice the EARLIEST_JOB column in the output, and how the aggregate function FIRST is used in the SELECT clause to calculate it.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions058.htm#SQLRF00641

```
select e.deptno, d.dname, min(e.hiredate) as earliest_hiredate,
       min(e.job) keep (dense_rank first order by e.hiredate) as earliest_job
from   emp e join dept d on e.deptno = d.deptno
group by e.deptno, d.dname
;

DEPTNO  DNAME       EARLIEST_HIREDATE    EARLIEST_JOB
------  ----------  -------------------  ------------
    10  ACCOUNTING  1981-06-09 00:00:00  MANAGER
    20  RESEARCH    1980-12-17 00:00:00  CLERK
    30  SALES       1981-02-20 00:00:00  SALESMAN
```